# Grab Youtube embed code from a post page in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, youtube

I need to somehow grab the embed code from a post page so I can include a small video version in the archives page. Basically instead of displaying the typical featured image and excerpt, I want to include a small version of the video, plus the excerpt. Similar to the Youtube search results page. 
The problem is, I believe the video code is within get_the_content();

This is in filters.php

```
function ar2_add_embed_container( $html ) {

    return '<div class="entry-embed">' . $html . '</div>';

}

add_filter( 'embed_oembed_html', 'ar2_add_embed_container' );
```

How do I make use of it? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Search for `oembed` in [wordpress.se], I'm quite sure I've seen related code over there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you brasolfilo, your suggestion lead me in the right direction.

I assumed that an embed was a custom "video" field automatically. This is not the case. For anyone who wishes to grab video for a video archive page you need first need to create this custom field on your posts

**Step 1:** Read this
http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields

Basically you're creating your custom field ( I named mine video, you can name it whatever)

**Step 2:** Within your loop

```
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

        $id = $post->ID;

        $video_url = get_post_meta($id, 'video', true);

        echo wp_oembed_get( $video_url, array( 'width' => 400 ) );

    endwhile;
```

Here's the codex for wp_oembed_get

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_oembed_get

That should give you a starting point to integrate into your template or whatever. :)